# Test Actor which use JPA.withTransaction (java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed when tested)

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, websocket, akka

I have wrote an Actor based `WebSocket` that is working correctly, but I need to test.

I have created WebSocket in Next way:

```
public static WebSocket<JsonNode> bulkEventsImportWebSocket() {
   return WebSocket.withActor(EventsImportActor::props);
}
```

My Actor is Next:

```
public class EventsImportActor extends UntypedActor {

   public static final Injector INJECTOR = Guice.createInjector(new DefaultModule());

   private static ObjectMapper mapper = INJECTOR.getInstance(ObjectMapper.class);

   public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
      Logger.info("EventsImportActor created");
      return Props.create(EventsImportActor.class, out);
   }

   private final ActorRef out;

   public EventsImportActor(ActorRef out) {
      this.out = out;
   }

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
      Logger.info("EventsImportActor received message");
/*
      self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), self());
*/
      try {

         JsonNode content = (JsonNode) message;

         JPA.withTransaction(() -> {
            someHugeImportOperationWithJPA(content)
         });
         Logger.info("EventsImportActor  message processed");
      } catch (Throwable e) {
         out.tell(ControllerUtils.getErrosObjectNode(e, mapper), self());
      }
   }
}
```

I have wrote next test:

```
public class EventsImportActorTest extends WithServer {


   public static final Injector INJECTOR = Guice.createInjector(new DefaultModule());
   private static ObjectMapper mapper = INJECTOR.getInstance(ObjectMapper.class);

   static ActorSystem system;


   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp(){
      system = ActorSystem.create();
      Logger.info("setUp done");
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void stopApp() {
      system.shutdown();
   }


 @Test
   public void bulkEventsImportWebSocketTest() throws Throwable {


      Props propsTest = Props.create(EventsImportTestActor.class);
      final ActorRef testActorRef = system.actorOf(propsTest);

      Props propsImport = EventsImportActor.props(testActorRef);
      ActorRef importActorRef = system.actorOf(propsImport);

      importActorRef.tell(mapper.readTree(""), testActorRef);

   }

}
```

My EventsImportTestActor will make assertions, it looks like this now:

```
public class EventsImportTestActor extends UntypedActor {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
      Logger.info("received by EventsImportTestActor message: " + message);
   }
}
```

When I run this test I receive `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: `EntityManager` is closed when tested
When I don't use JPA it is working correctly.

How I should change my Test to give an actor an access to DB (valid access to `EntityManager` )?

Answer (score 0):

Changed test to next

`   @Test
    public void bulkEventsImportWebSocketTest() throws Throwable {

```
    Props propsTest = Props.create(EventsImportTestActor.class);
    final ActorRef testActorRef = system.actorOf(propsTest);

    EventJsonDataFormat format = new EventJsonDataFormat(mapper, occurrenceDAO);
    JsonNode content = mapper.readTree("");

    Logger.info("content: " + content);
    JPA.withTransaction(() -> {
        EventsImportActor.bulkImport(format.importFromJson(content), testActorRef, testActorRef);
    });
}
```

`

and convert bulkImport method to static by passing there self() ref

```
bulkImport(format.importFromJson(content), out, this.self());
```